# Scrapy links queue

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Is there a way to personalize scrapy links queue? I was thinking about creating a ranking system, so that the links that have higher probability to meet my parsing criteria have priority. I would like to know if this is possible within the scrapy module., and if so where can I find documentation about it (I havent been able to find so far).

Comment: there is [DEPTH_PRIORITY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-priority) and [SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#scheduler-priority-queue) but I never used it

Comment: [Requests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) has parameter `priority`

Comment: This will work for me! Thanks